# In Windows 8.1, which process handles audio?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, audio, process

I have been messing around and I'm curious to which process - if there is one - handles audio and sound. Thanks!

Comment: The process that handles the audio would be whatever application program that you start.  The kernel only provides system calls, which would be used by the user application(s).

Answer (score 1):

The sound in Windows since Windows Vista is handled by the process [`audiodg.exe`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/01/31/what-is-audiodg-exe.aspx) in `C:\Windows\System32\` and the `windows audio service`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no process that handles audio it is part of the windows kernel itself via the "[Core Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802(v=vs.85).aspx)" subsystem.